# Serilog: Open log file

Tags: c#, serilog

Is there a way to get the full filename from the Log Class?
The logger creates a file with a format like `C:\MyPath\log-20160631.txt`

I can not access the source filename which i used for the init of the logger.

Edit:
Here is the init of the logger:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.LiterateConsole()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"C:\MyPath\log.txt")
            .CreateLogger();
```

In every location in the code i can use e.g. `Log.Information()` but how i get the Sink information? I want to get the filename which i passed to rolling file sink.

My current workaround is to generate the real file manually (crazy ugly code):

```
public string LogFilename
{
   get
   {
      string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(LogFilenameTemplate);
      string filenameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(LogFilenameTemplate);
      string extension = Path.GetExtension(LogFilenameTemplate);
      string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
      string fullFilename = Path.Combine(path, filenameWithoutExtension + "-" + date + extension);
      return fullFilename;
   }
}
```

Format i got from [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile).

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "I can not access the source filename which i used for the init of the logger.".  Please post your serilog initialization code and clarify exactly where and why you need the filename.

Comment: I added the example code and a extended description and a current workaround.

Comment: From skimming [through the code](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile/tree/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile/Sinks/RollingFile), I don't think it's possible to get the filename currently being used.  I guess another question would be why to do you need it?  Perhaps there's another way of doing what you need to do without knowing filename.

Comment: I pass the Logger to an other part of an application (programed not by me). And there is a need to open the log file in the UI.
So i should pass :) the filename as well, with the ugly workaround.

Comment: If you absolutely need to use the filesystem to share access to the logs, make sure you [set the `shared` flag to `true`](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/08/atomic-shared-log-file-writes/).  But it might be easier to find a different way to share the log data than relying on a filename.

Answer (score 9):

No, there's no way to retrieve the filename from Serilog. Your best available option is to use the `System.IO` classes to list files in the directory, and then open the one with the most recent modification date.